# Mapping DialogFlow Extracted Parameters to Database column values

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

What is the suggested solution for handling the mapping of extracted parameters from an intents training phrases to a user-defined value in a database specific to that user.

A practical example I think would be a shopping list app.

Through a Web UI, the user adds `catchup` to a shopping list which is stored in the database as `item`.

Then through that agent (i.e. Google Assistant), the utterance results in `ketchup` being extracted as the `item` parameter. I wouldn't have a way to know how to map the extracted parameter from the utterance to the user defined value in the daabase

So just to be clear

```
// in the database added by the user from a web UI
"catchup"

// extracted from voice utterance
"ketchup"
```

How should I accomplish making sure that the extracted parameters can be matched up to the free form values they have added to the list?

Also, I am inexperienced in this area and have looked through the docs quite a bit and may just be missing this. Wasn't sure if Developer entities, or Session Entities was the solution for this or not.

Answer (score 0):

Either Developer or Session Entities may be useful here. It depends.

- If you can enumerate all the possible things that a user can say, and possibly create aliases for some of them, then you should use a Developer Entity. This is easiest and works the best - the ML system has a better chance of matching words when they are pre-defined as part of the training model.
- If you can't do that, and its ok that you just want to match things that they have *already* added to a database, then a Session Entity will work well. This really is best for things that you already have about the user, or which may change dramatically based on context.

You may even wish to offer a combination - define as many entities as you can (to get the most common replies), allow free-form replies, and incorporate these free-form replies as Session Entities.

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand how this would work if I understand them correctly. Developer entities wouldn't work I don't think because a "master list" of possible items would cause conflicts between users. This is more likely in a non-shopping example, but an app that each user inputs a list of children. User A might input "Jon", User B might input "John". Is this the problem that session entities would solve?

Comment: I took a longer look at https://github.com/dialogflow/city-streets-trivia-nodejs and I don't see how session entities per that example would work for entities that had values specific to rows in a database specific to a user. This example uses cities and streets which are defined up front, but overrides the entity each time. How would this work if I was the user, and my utterance had to map to something I specifically added to the database previously? Another example would be a TODO list. How would I fulfill the utterance "Please mark [insert todo here] done"?

Comment: If I added through a Web UI for a TODO list app, "Call John". and then added another item "Call Jon" (because I have a friends both named John and Jon". When I utter "Please mark Call XXXX complete" how does it know which one to mark as complete? I certainly can't dynamically add all these to an entity list dynamically